# How to print foreign key of this model in django?

Tags: django, django-models, foreign-keys, django-queryset

Model File

```
class Report_item(models.Model):
owner = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, default=1)
title = models.CharField(max_length=255, help_text='*Title for the post e.g. item identity')
item_type = models.CharField(default="", max_length=100,
                             help_text='*Enter the item name you found e.g. Marksheet,key,wallet')
location = models.CharField(max_length=60, help_text='*Enter the address/street where you find this item')
city = models.CharField(max_length=60, help_text='*Enter the city name')
date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
Description = models.TextField(help_text='*Enter full description about item')
publish = models.BooleanField(default=False)

image = models.FileField(default="add Item image",
                         help_text='*Please uplocad a item image to identify by the owner')

def __str__(self):
    return self.title + "      " + str(self.publish)

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('feed:detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

class Meta:
    ordering = ["-date"]
```

I print my title in the shell.

```
>>> qs=Report_item.objects.filter(id=3)
>>> print(qs[0].title)
bunch of key with home keyring
```

But I got an error when I tried to print(qs[0].owner)

My foreign key is the Django auth user.

```
    >>> print(qs[0].owner)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/imsaiful/Desktop/local_repo/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py", line 178, in __get__
    rel_obj = getattr(instance, self.cache_name)
AttributeError: 'Report_item' object has no attribute '_owner_cache'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/imsaiful/Desktop/local_repo/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py", line 184, in __get__
    rel_obj = self.get_object(instance)
  File "/home/imsaiful/Desktop/local_repo/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py", line 159, in get_object
    return qs.get(self.field.get_reverse_related_filter(instance))
  File "/home/imsaiful/Desktop/local_repo/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 379, in get
    self.model._meta.object_name
django.contrib.auth.models.DoesNotExist: User matching query does not exist.
```

admin section image:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lQ-TcdaTCxj-cmnzfhlGZXql-KbWpIjW/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Please share the error, why do you specify `default=1`, looks quite unsafe, since it is possible that this key does *not* eixsts.

Comment: First I create a model without a foreign key and insert some rows. But when I need to add foreign key then I have to add a default value for the existing rows. So I add default=1. I add the error in the question body.

Comment: @imaiful: but I have the idea that the Id you stored (probably `1`) simply does *not* map on a `User`. This error means that the `id` you use does not exist in the "id space" of `User`s.

Comment: Sir Id is the post ID. I need to print the owner of the post. So I need to print owner name who add the post. Example one user add the post. The post id is 3. So I fetch the detail like title, location etc from the post id. But I am getting an error when I need to print the post owner.I am going to add the admin panel. Please see the screenshot in the post. This is very important for my college project.

Comment: Yes,exactly. But now you want the owner. Now in a relational database you do *not* store the details of the owner itself in the post entry, you store the id (probably in the `owner_id` column, you can check the database for that). But it is possible that this id simply does not match with a `User` row, and thus the database is in a corrupt state, unfortunately by hardcoding `default=1`, one can say that the database is already "corrupt by design". You probably have no user with `id=1`, hence if the `owner_id` is 1, then there raises a problem.

Comment: Sir, now I have removed the default =1  and migrate my database again. But still getting the same error.

Comment: of course, since you *already* corrupted the database. Take a look at the table with a Database editor tool, the `default` is only used when *creating* a row, you thus already created a database where foreign key constraints no longer hold. So the rows that are already constructed will have to be "repaired" (probably manually).

Comment: @imsaiful `owner` is referencing `User` model. Since it is referencing `user_id=1` - does it exist? Do you have any `users` in your DB? @Willem  is absolutely correct about your issue.

Comment: You were right sir. There was two field where there no foreign key exist. I add the foreign key manually now print(qs[0].owner) perfectly giving the owner name. Thanks for your help. Could you please connect to me two or more days.  I need you to complete my silly mistakes. Thanks for your all help sir. I was stuck in this problem since evening.

Comment: Thanks a ton, both of you. This is my first question on StackOverflow and you solved the issue within half an hour.